# Prove that every bounded sequence in a separable Hilbert space has a weakly convergent subsequence.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I was suggested to use the Banach-Alaoglu theorem (which makes sense: similar hypothesis, same thesis), the only problem is that the only version I know from my course of real analysis deals with $L^p$ spaces, so I guess it's not the most general version. I have two questions: first I need to find a book or an article where there is a complete version of Banach-Alaoglu, in the most general way and I'll be glad if someone could help me. Then, anyone knows a solution or can give me any hint to solve the exercise, whether using Banach-Alaoglu or not? (If possible, without using advanced functional analysis results).

Comment: Look it up on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%E2%80%93Alaoglu_theorem).  BTW, a separable Hilbert space can be represented as an $L^2$ space, so the version you have is not really less general than what you need.

Comment: @RobertIsrael can you tell me where I can find this representation?

Comment: Let $(e_j)_{j\in J}$ be an orthonormal basis. Then $H\to l^2(J), x\mapsto (\langle x,e_j\rangle)_{j\in J}$ is an isometric isomorphism. No need for seperability by the way.

Comment: @LeBtz I guess you need separability because the existence of an orthonormal basis is not always guaranteed. Thank you for the help

Comment: @M.Springsteen That's wrong. Every hilbert space has an orthonormal basis. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthonormal_basis#Existence for example.

Comment: I must have misunderstood something at lesson, thank you

Comment: I believe this is true for all reflexive spaces, not just separable Hilbert spaces. This is because the unit ball in a reflexive space is weakly compact by Banach-Alaoglu, and by Eberlein-Smulian weak compactness is equivalent to weak sequential compactness for Banach spaces.